# How I can update one database schema to another database?

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 databases in the same postgresql server:

- `mybd`: used for development
- `test_mydb`: used for testing is is preseeded with some test data that are significantly smaller than `mydb`

The `mydb` is updated via migration scripts. What I want is to sync the changes after the migrations are run into the `test_mydb` afterwards, I want to `pg_dump` the contents of `test_mydb` in order to generate a test dump.

Is there a way to look for diferences between 2 schemas of the database `mydb` and `test_mydb` and apply them to `test_mydb`?

I want schema-only differences and not full data replication.

Comment: Could you not run the same migration scripts on the test_mydb database?

Comment: In my current setup no because I run them during unit test. Also the same database is shared across multipl projects as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pg_dump` to generate the DB object scripts, then compare the text files. Not sure whether `pg_dump` generate the objects in specific order. If yes, you can use a program like `diff` to do the comparison. Otherwise, you may need to compare manually.

The following `pg_dump` options will be useful

```
  -n, --schema=PATTERN         dump the specified schema(s) only
  -s, --schema-only            dump only the schema, no data
```